# Get process handle by filepath in Windows

Tags: c, windows, process

I am trying to get a process handle from an exe's filepath in C in Windows, I cannot find much online about this unfortunately. I have tried using the OpenProcess function, however this requires more information than just a filepath. Is it possible to get a list of all the running processes and compare their filepaths to obtain the process handle?

Comment: This example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes with `GetModuleFileNameEx` instead of `GetModuleBaseName` should get you started.

Comment: What if there are multiple processes loaded from the same exe?